# Mockito is giving infinite while loops and finite for loops on the same NavigationSet

Tags: java, loops, junit, mockito

- I am using **Mockito** in a **JUnit test**. I mocked a `NavigableSet`.
- In my unit test at some point I need to loop into the objects contained in this `NavigableSet`.
- I planned this `NavigableSet`, for testing purposes, to contain only 1 object.

The following is the code I used with Mockito to create the mock object:

```
NavigableSet<ObjectToProcess> newMockedSet = new TreeSet<ObjectToProcess>();
ObjectToProcess mockedInnerObject = new ObjectToProcess(); // initialization of this object
newMockedSet.add(mockedInnerObject); // I just added the only 1 object contained in the NavigableSet
Mockito.when(getSetOfObjectToProcess()).thenReturn(newMockedSet);
```

Why the following `while` loop is giving an infinite loop with a `NavigableSet` containing only 1 object?

```
NavigableSet<ObjectToProcess> anotherSetOfObjects = getSetOfObjectToProcess(); // retrieving the mocked object
while (anotherSetOfObjects.iterator().hasNext())
{
    ObjectToProcess thisPaymentDemand = anotherSetOfObjects.iterator().next();
    // do stuff
}
```

Why the following `for` loop is behaving as expected looping only once?

```
NavigableSet<ObjectToProcess> anotherSetOfObjects = getSetOfObjectToProcess(); // retrieving the mocked object
for (ObjectToProcess thisMockedInnerObject : anotherSetOfObjects)
{
    ObjectToProcess thisPaymentDemand = thisMockedInnerObject;
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a Mockito problem.

In the **while** example you're calling `anotherSetOfObjects.iterator()` at the start of your loop on **EACH** iteration.

You're getting an iterator (for the mockedSet which contains a single item), then checking if it has next (it does), then entering the body of your loop.  After the body completes, then you're running the conditional check again to see whether to loop...by getting a **NEW** iterator, which functions exactly the same as the first one (assuming you haven't modified the set in the meantime).

Store the iterator outside the loop so you're testing the same iterator on each iteration rather than getting a new one:

```
Iterator<NavigableSet> iterator = anotherSetOfObjects.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext())
{
    ObjectToProcess thisPaymentDemand = anotherSetOfObjects.iterator().next();
    // do stuff
}
```

Doing this will make your while loop behave as your for loop does.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to understand your intention from the code posted.  You need to demonstrate the creation of a mock object of some collaborating class type and the identity of the class you are testing.  Also, the argument of a `when()` call is supposed to be of the form of a method call on a Mockito mock.  In other words,

```
// setting up test fixture
MyCollaborator x = Mockito.mock(MyCollaborator.class);
when(x.getSetOfObjectToProcess()).thenReturn(newMockedSet);

// and then later in test
NavigableSet<ObjectToProcess> anotherSetOfObjects = x.getSetOfObjectToProcess();
while(anotherSetOfObjects.iterator() ...) {

// or
for (ObjectToProcess thisMockedInnerObject : anotherSetOfObjects) {
...
```

So you are missing the `x.` part of the `when()` argument.

What is less clear is what your intention is in the first place.  If you are trying to test the method `getSetOfObjectToProcess()` on some class, then you shouldn't be mocking that class.  You should only be mocking collaborator classes/objects that interact with the class you are testing (often known as the "System Under Test" or SUT).

Your code does not even show the creation of a Mockito mock object with the `Mockito.mock()` method or the `@Mock` annotation, and at least one of those is necessary to use Mockito.  And if `getSetOfObjectToProcess()` is a static method, then Mockito will not mock it for you regardless.